# NextJS type error: Cannot find name 'NextApplicationPage'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

`const { Component, pageProps}: { Component: NextApplicationPage; pageProps: any } = props`

When I write the above code and set Component type to NextApplicationPage. I get an error saying,
*Cannot find name 'NextApplicationPage'*

I have to use the above mentioned type for Component, because I have to access `requireAuth` property from from `Component`

Please help

Comment: question contains very less details. Can you try importing the type for `NextApplicationPage` or also try doing `{ Component: typeof import(NextApplicationPage)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extends the props of next:

```
import { AppProps } from "next/app"
import { NextPage } from "next"
...

export type NextApplicationPage<P = any, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  requireAuth?: boolean
}
...

const { Component, pageProps }: { Component: NextApplicationPage; pageProps: any } = props as AppProps
```